# Issue with JUnit and Class Loaders

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm working on a Maven project in IntelliJ whose tree looks like:

```
-resources (marked as default resource folder)  
-src
```

Inside src there are

```
-src/main  
-src/test
```

While inside resources there's a file called "windows.json" that i need to parse.

As of now, the class that needs to parse the json is `src/main/java/utils/WindowBuilder.Java` and I'm using an `InputStreamReader` by passing to its constructor:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("windows.json");
```

The code works just fine on its own, but if I try to run tests from `src/test` using `WindowBuilder` class I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to retrieve the resource.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add your resource at: src/test/resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct tree structure in a maven project is:

[image]

Add your resource files for tests in resources folder under test.

Comment: Thank you, i thought resources had to be a shared folder at the same height as src.